# Getting False for an equality that I know it is true

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-test

I am getting false for an equality that I know it is true(I proved it by hand and I used sagemath to see that it is true) however when using Mathematica it is giving false although I used `TrueQ` with `Simplify`.
The equality that I want to check is the following: `xi` and `H` are vectors having 3 components

```
B = Cross[xi, H]
b = B.B, 
TrueQ[(H.xi)^2*(xi.xi) == (H.H)*(xi.xi)^2 - b*(xi.xi)//Simplify]
```

And the answer is `False`!

Comment: Your code maybe `B = Cross[xi, H];
b = B . B;
TrueQ[(H . xi)^2*(xi . xi) == (H . H)*(xi . xi)^2 - b*(xi . xi) // 
  Simplify]`

Comment: The `TrueQ` command is not an appropriate command to this end. The documentation clear says

" `TrueQ` will return `True` only if the input is explicitly `True`"

For example, `TrueQ[(a + b)^2 == a^2 + 2*a*b + b^2]` returns `False`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative answer using components for the vectors:

```
xi = {x1, x2, x3};
H = {H1, H2, H3};
B = Cross[xi, H]; b = B.B;
(H.xi)^2*(xi.xi) - ((H.H) (xi.xi)^2 - b (xi.xi)) // FullSimplify
```

returns

> 0

hence the identity is true. In principle the vectors could also be complex as the components are unspecified.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Assumptions = 
 xi ∈ Vectors[3, Reals] && H ∈ Vectors[3, Reals]
B = Cross[xi, H];
 b = B . B;
(H . xi)^2*(xi . xi) == (H . H) (xi . xi)^2 - 
   b (xi . xi) // TensorReduce
```

> `True`

Comment: +1 You can also do this with complex components as well as with symbolic dimensions, `$Assumptions = xi \[Element] Vectors[dim] && H \[Element] Vectors[dim];`